# PHP Encrypt/Decrypt using OpenSSL not working for me

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to use PHP and OpenSSL to encrypt some data using a public key, and then decrypt it again.

I generated a public.key and private.key using this code:

```
// generate private key
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 1024,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));
// write private key to file
openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privateKey, 'private.key');
// generate public key from private key
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
// write public key to file
file_put_contents('public.key', $publicKey['key']);
// clear key
openssl_free_key($privateKey);
```

My code to encrypt and decrypt is basically straight from the PHP documentation:

```
// data to encrypt
$data = "This is a long string or other bit of data that i want to encrypt";

// ==== ENCRYPT ====

// read public key
$publicKey =  file_get_contents("public.key");
$publicKey = openssl_get_publickey($publicKey);

// encrypt data using public key into $sealed
$sealed = '';
openssl_seal($data, $sealed, $ekeys, array($publicKey));
openssl_free_key($publicKey);

// ==== DECRYPT ====

// get private key to decrypt with
$privateKey = file_get_contents("private.key");
$privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey($privateKey);

// decrypt data using private key into $open
$open = '';
openssl_open($sealed, $open, $env_key, $privateKey);
openssl_free_key($privateKey);


// display decrypted data:
echo "<p>Decrypted data: ".$open;
```

Anyone got any clue why it is not working, or at least a way to find out what error is happening?

Comment: First of all, check the values of all variables to make sure they contain what you think they should contain :)

Comment: @Jack Cheers yes I think everything is as it should be. Its just refusing to decrypt the data as far as I can tell. I've pasted an example here: http://pastebin.com/HMGg7FSg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget this statement?

```
$env_key = $ekeys[0];
```

I found my answer by reading the example code for [`openssl_seal()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php)

Comment: Yes! Envelope keys, that was it, thanks v much!
I wish there was better documentation on the function description about that